# Can I have <loc> element & <sitemapindex> element within the same XML for Sitemap?

Tags: xml, seo, sitemap

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" 
  xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1" 
  xmlns:video="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-video/1.1">
  <url>
    <loc>http://www.example.com/foo.html</loc>
  </url>
  <sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
   <sitemap>
      <loc>http://www.example.com/sitemap1.xml.gz</loc>
      <lastmod>2004-10-01T18:23:17+00:00</lastmod>
   </sitemap>
   <sitemap>
      <loc>http://www.example.com/sitemap2.xml.gz</loc>
      <lastmod>2005-01-01</lastmod>
   </sitemap>
   </sitemapindex>
</urlset>
```

Can I have the `url` and `sitemapindex` within the same sitemap XML file? I have around 300K plus pages in the website. Also there are close to 50 static HTML pages. So I want to add these static URLs directly under the `url` tag and for dynamic URLs I create a sitemap index.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that will not work. In Search Console (former Webmaster Tools) you will get an "Unexpected tag" error message and the sitemap will be dropped.

Your best bet is to create a separate sitemap for those 50 HTML pages, and then include that sitemap in your sitemap index file.